# Embedding Doxygen Group/Section/Anchor/etc output onto a Page

Tags: c, doxygen

My goal is to create a standalone Page that includes sections of code by reference or grouping like in modules. I am aware of Doxygen's ability to provide links to the desired sections, and the grouping feature for modules. However, the output format calls for a Page, but I need some of the features for Modules (grouping). **Can Doxygen "expand" links to "embed" the generated output in place of a link?** If I were to print this Page or Group, hyperlinks would be useless.

Currently, I have a Group (module) that contains the primary sections of code of interest within a primary header file. However, I can not move many of the referenced enumerations or macros. I could continue to use @addtogroup on related fragments, but because it is a Group styled page, I have to use a custom DoxygenLayout.xml to remove unnecessary sections. This layout only should apply to this one group.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you add a small example of what you want and the used settings (i.e. the ones different from the default settings, so the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) and add this to the question. Did you have a look t the `\snippet` command?

Comment: Version 1.9.6. the `\snippet` is very close to what I am looking for, but it merely copies the lines into a code block.  Thanks for pointing it out. It seems to good enough to include the members of an enum when each is a "mode" for a function. But now Doxygen is combining multi-line comments. The first member of a `@if CUSTOMER @ingroup customer-group @endif @{` group is receiving the [cust-topic] label into its description.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by albert, @snippet was very close to what I needed. Although, labels needed to be placed as such

```
/// [docs-section1]
enum, macros, etc.
/// [docs-section1]
```

and then referenced with

```
@snippet file.h docs-section1
```

I did not want Doxygen comment headers for enums included, so I placed the opening label at the bottom of such, or on its own single line Doxygen comment between the header and the enum. Whether it was placed before or after, Doxygen merged it into the documentation of the enum or macro that followed. So enums and macros had a stray "*/" or "[docs-section]" in their @details. (Doxygen merges multiple comment sections together).

Another method, in conjuction with Doxygen's conditionals (similar to pre-processor predefined)

```
/**
 * @if DOCS
 *   @ingroup my-doc-group
 * @endif
 */
```

I could bypass this bug. But, this works great for enums, and could work for a series of macros if they were next to each other using @{...@}. But, the label section worked better for such macros.

Another side-effect of this is that members cannot be documented more than once in different groups. This was fine as I only need this one group. I got all but one to move to this new group.

These two methods began bloating the documentation until I came across the @dontinclude command. The following is a happy medium between the above two commands:

```
/**
 * @brief lalala
 * @details
 * | A | Table |
 *
 * @dontinclude file.h
 * @skip first-enum-member-or-macro
 * @until last-enum-member-or-macro
 */
```

If it is a single macro, @skipline provided the entire line that the text pattern was found on. These commands allow me to simply include snippets of code without having to provide additional Doxygen labels or commands in the source to be included.